# Testing association with 0-1 independent variable - how?

Tags: correlation, binary-data

I'm looking to demonstrate an association between penalty (overtime) payments and absenteeism. The dependent variable is overtime payments ($0-$highval) for a shift, and the outcome variable is 'was the person absent (sick) for this shift'.

What I'd planned on doing was:
a) bucketing overtime payments eg. $0, $0-$50, $51-$100 etc. then
b) correlating this against '% of shifts with this particular penalty payment where the person 'went sick' (which is a variable that is either 'at work' or 'absent'.

So the output would be something like:

```
Penalty      %Shifts not worked
0              13%
50+            6%
100+           3%
```

This obviously requires a bit of data pre-processing, which I'd like to avoid in taking a first-pass look at the issue.

Is there a more basic/efficient way to test a continuous dependent variable like $ overtime paid and a 0-1 variable (at work/absent)?
Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: Have you considered doing a simple regression on the problem?  I would give more suggestions but I am unsure by your problem statement if your outcome is continuous or a 0-1 variable?

Comment: BabakP, the outcome is a 0-1 variable: they person was either sick or at work.

Comment: Ok, then I believe you mean to say independent and not dependent here: "The dependent variable is overtime payments..." because the word dependent is usually associated with the outcome variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand you have a binary variable and a continuous variable. Unless you have a very good reason why, I don't suggest categorizing the overtime payments variable as you are simply throwing away information into more simpler and less useful forms

You can simply use a pearson correlation between the two. This is called point-biserial correlation. The p-value you get with the correlation is the same p-value you get with a t-test. You can also calculate the confidence interval of the mean difference in pay between the categories at work and absent.

More importantly, before you calculate any numbers, I hope you plotted the data. Use a side-by-side boxplot, one for at work, another for absent. This should be more telling than any test. For example, if you identify extreme outliers, non-parametric inferences may be better.

Comment: Thanks Hotaka and BabakP - I will simply run a regression through r and do the boxplot (whisker too). Hotaka, yes I did have a concern that I was throwing out data by categorising. In terms of the PHP/MySQL code, I've also taken a quick look by calculating % sick leave shifts for each category of penalty (there are only 5 - 0, 15%, 17.5%, 22.5% and 100%). By ignoring the dollars (which are continuous) and focussing on the rates only (categorical) I'm able to simplify my MySQL/PHP processing, which was the main concern with trying to identify the right approach. I'll use R to do the rest. Tks